# Changing the position of the images on user selection in a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of images in columns. I want to change the position of the image when user clicks on the image. I want to change the position of the image to the top image in that column. Please give me some idea how to do it.

Comment: Can you post your markup and the code you tried?

Comment: Please provide some code to make this question less generic. It is hard to help you, when we don't know what we are working with

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Either you manipulate the DOM or you change the CSS class. Dom manipulation way :

```
document.getElementById(parentNode.id).removeChild(this);
document.getElementById(parentNode.id).prependChild(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying my question. I am voting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .detach() command from jquery, it will allow you to set it back in later with all the events intact: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/QnWhR/

```
$('img').click(function() {
    var x = $(this).detach();
    x.prependTo('body');
});
```

animated version: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/PXPgT/